# Prevent double lookup of the same element in Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I know there is no `reference to "struct" variable` in C#, but this is the case where it would come handy

```
    Dictionary<int, int> d = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    d.Add(1, 1);

    ++d[1];
    ++d[1];
```

how can I perform 2 operations (increment in this case) on the same element without using `operator[]` twice (to prevent double lookup)?

Comment: The whole point of a hashed data structure (dictionaries, hashsets, etc.) is that lookups are cheap.

Comment: You're actually performing *four* lookups in this case - get, then set, then get, then set. But do you have any reason to think that's actually a problem in your real application?

Comment: Easy answer: You capture the first result. Hard answer: Do some research.

Comment: @JonSkeet: An update only needs to take a single lookup when done properly.

Comment: @leppie But he's not just performing an update; he's performing an increment.  That needs to get the value in order to figure out what value to set.  Had he written `d[1] = 2; d[1] = 3;` then that wouldn't need the two gets.  Unless you mean that it is indeed possible to write your own dictionary that has an `Update` method that accepts a predicate that is given the old value and that returns the new value.  Yes, you can write a hash-based lookup that does that, but you can't do it with `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`.

Comment: @Servy: For an update, the location to the bucket should be stored, so it can happen in-place (in the ideal world). Update: Was not aware this was not possible in .NET

Comment: @leppie By that do you mean that in an ideal world `Dictionary` would expose means of both fetching and setting a value using a single lookup, or do you mean that he should be changing his code (but using the existing `Dictionary` implementation) to perform a single lookup?  To do what you want to do would require functionality that the system `Dictionary` doesn't expose.

Comment: @Servy: I think I gathered that now. This theoretical debate has happened before, but I could not confirm it (then).

Comment: Note that `ConcurrentDictionary<,>` has `AddOrUpdate` which can perform an effectively in-place update. But `Dictionary<,>` doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a mutable reference type that wraps another value, in this case an immutable value type, allowing the value of the wrapper to be mutated:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

This lets you write:

```
Dictionary<int, Wrapper<int>> d = new Dictionary<int, Wrapper<int>>();

d.Add(1, new Wrapper<int>(){Value = 1});

var wrapper = d[1];
wrapper.Value++;
wrapper.Value++;
```

Comment: so answer is "it is not possible to avoid lookups on immutable types" ?

Comment: @relaxxx It's impossible to make more than one edit to the value of a dictionary where the values are immutable without performing multiple lookups, yes.  You can't get a reference to the bucket for that dictionary's value and continue setting it without doing a lookup.  You could write your own `Dictionary` implementation that exposed that functionality of course.

Comment: ok, thank you. I am coming from C++ and its iterators and pointer etc, where such stuff are possible

Comment: @relaxxx C# has iterators and pointers as well (along with other similar constructs that can perform similar operations).  The `Dictionary` class simply doesn't expose any means of using them.  It could have.  What I showed is one way; they could have simply had the getter return a mutable wrapper.  In C++ they'd need to expose the address of the storage location in some way for you to use a pointer; if the lookup didn't explicitly support the idea of an iterator (something you could implement in a C# dictionary) you couldn't do it there either.  It's the  implementation, not the language.

Comment: What I meant was that C++ container works over iterators. It is of course by container design, not by language capabilities... However  in C++ you can take an address of POD type. Even though no standard guarantee you can access for example unordered_map (hashmap) with pointers, once you do lookup, you can take pointer and work with him,unless you performing some other operation which can cause changing inner state (adding element, ..)

Comment: @relaxxx The address of the value of a key that is looked up is highly unlikely to be exposed externally unless the designers of the data structure went out of their way to expose it.